# on the bank/on a bank

Tags: articles

**Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do.**

I am trying to understand why Lewis Carroll decided to write "on the bank" instead of "on a bank". Could you clarify it for me? So far I've been exposed to the following possible reasons for that:

1. "on a bank" is never correct in the sense of "on a riverbank". (Do you agree?)
2. Alice was beginning to get tired of sitting on a specific bank which happens to be "the bank".

However, I am not convinced whether "sitting on a bank" wouldn't convey the meaning needed.  I understand that "was getting tired" restricts the situation to a one-off occasion. Hence, she couldn't have been sitting on more than one banks at the same time. It means that "a bank" can be only a specific bank. I think if we had "She was tired of sitting on a bank" it would mean that she might have sat on many banks. But it's not the case in this case.

These are my musings on the matter. How would you profoundly substantiate the choice of "the"?

Comment: We should note that this is the very first sentence of *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, and Lewis Carroll was using a technique called *in medias res*, where we just start in the middle of things.  We don't know who Alice is or why she is sitting on the bank by her sister or why she is getting tired of it, but the sentence is written as though we already knew these things.  That may partly explain Carroll's choice of **the bank** instead of **a bank**.

Answer (score 5):

Stangdon's comment has the answer, but I'll enlarge it a bit.

You're right that normally we use *the* when we expect the reader/hearer to know which thing(s) we are talking about, often because they have already been mentioned. So a possible way of starting the book could be:

> Alice was sitting on a bank by her sister, and was getting beginning to get very tired.

But writers will often make the narrative more engaging for the reader by writing as though the reader already knows (this is what stangdon means by *in medias res* - thanks, I know the phrase, but I wasn't aware of this use of it).

Charlotte Bronte begins *Jane Eyre* with:

> There was no possibility of taking a walk that day.

In normal speech, *that day* would not make sense unless the conversation had already established which day *that day* was; but by starting the narrative in this way, Bronte inviting us to enter Jane's story. *Jane* knows which day she is talking about - the day on which the first chapter is set - and by presenting it to us as *that day*, as though we also knew which day she was talking about, she invites us to share her perspective on what happened.

Comment: Can this "Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on A bank" mean that she she was getting tired of sitting on any riverbank not that specific one?

Comment: Yes, it could. Because it begins with Alice getting tired (her inner state), it also takes the reader into her view of the world, and suggests that the bank is without interest to her - it's just _a_ bank in her mind, and not _the bank she is sitting on_,. This is quite a subtle distinction.